# generic swift object serialization?

Tags: swift, serialization, deserialization

Is there a generic way to serialize/deserialize objects for iOS? I was using the following code, and the system functions I was calling were deprecated in iOS 12:

```
  func object(forKey:String) -> Any? {
    if let data = get(BLOB_COL, forKey) {
      return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data as! Data)
    }
    return nil
  }

  func set(_ object:Any, forKey: String) {
    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: object)
    updateOrInsert(forKey, BLOB_COL, data)
  }
```

It looks like the new versions of these functions requires knowledge of the object classes, and different signatures for unarchiving different collection types... is there a simple way to handle this generically?

Comment: ***generic**ally* contains the keyword.

Comment: Forget about NSKeyedArchiver and start using Codable protocol.

Comment: Btw it looks like this is extending UserDefaults. Please edit your question and post a [mcve]

Comment: It's actually a replacement for UserDefaults - this is a workaround because my app runs in the background, and UserDefaults didn't work when the device was locked.

Comment: @Crag if you really want to keep using `NSKeyedArchiver` to persist your app `Data` just change `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject`  to  `NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data)` and `NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData` to `NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: object, requiringSecureCoding: false)`

Comment: @LeoDabus I'm not married to the NSKeyed... classes, but the functions you mentioned look like what I'm looking for - it looks like Codable still takes class params and needs special handling for collections. I'm testing this now, want to make your comment an Answer so it can be accepted after I verify it works for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to use NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver:

When archiving change:

```
NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData...
```

to

```
NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: object, requiringSecureCoding: false)
```

And when unarchiving change

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject...
```

to

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(data)
```

---

**Codable protocol generic approach**

If you would like to use Codable to encode and decode (serialize) your `Data` you can extend Encodable protocol and create a method to encode any object that conforms to it:

```
extension Encodable {
    func data(using encoder: JSONEncoder = JSONEncoder()) throws -> Data { try encoder.encode(self) }
}
```

And to decode the encoded data you can extend `Data` and create a generic method that decode any object that conforms to Decodable:

```
extension Data {
    func object<T: Decodable>(using decoder: JSONDecoder = JSONDecoder()) throws -> T {
        try decoder.decode(T.self, from: self)
    }
    // you can also create a string property to convert the JSON data to String
    var string: String? { String(data: self, encoding: .utf8) }
}
```

Usage:

```
struct Person: Codable {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
}
```

---

```
do {
    // encoding
    let person = Person(name: "Joe", age: 10)
    var people = [Person]()
    people.append(person)
    let data = try people.data()
    print(data.string ?? "")  // [{"name":"Joe","age":10}]
    // decoding
    let loadedPeople: [Person] = try data.object()
    loadedPeople.forEach({print( $0.name, $0.age)})  // Joe 10
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Leo says, stop using NSKeyedArchiver and use the Codable protocol. That's the modern, Swifty way to serialize/deserialize your objects.